# How to select the replaced text on the contenteditable area

Tags: javascript, html

I have implemented the feature which wraps selected text in tag. You can try it clicking the 'Apply Style' button.
And also I have implemented the feature removing the tag.
I want to keep the text selected when the tag is removed but I don't know how to implement it.
I have tried it on the following code but it doesn't work...
I run this code on Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/f5HaK/3/

http://youtube.com/watch?v=VtBSJzoTmys&feature=youtu.be

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
    <input id="applyStyle" type="button" value="Apply Style" />
    <input id="removeStyle" type="button" value="Remove Style" />    
</div>
<div contenteditable="true">hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
$(function(){

    var TextManager = function(){
        var sel;
        var naked;
    };

    TextManager.prototype = {
        execCommand: function(commandWithArgs, valueArg){
            var commandArr = commandWithArgs.split(' '),
            command = commandArr.shift(),
            args = commandArr.join(' ') + (valueArg || '');
            document.execCommand(command, 0, args);
        },
        applyStyle: function(tagName, className){
            this.sel = window.getSelection();
            var snipet = '<' + tagName + ' class="' + className + '" >' + this.sel.toString() + '</' + tagName + '>';
            this.execCommand('insertHTML', snipet);
            console.log(this.sel);
            this.sel.extend(this.sel.focusNode, 0);
        },
        removeStyle: function(){
            var jcurnode = $(this.sel.focusNode.parentNode);
            this.naked = jcurnode.text();
            jcurnode.replaceWith(this.naked);

            this.sel.extend(this.sel.focusNode, this.naked.length); //here, I'm trying to select text again which I removed the style.
        },
    };

    textManager = new TextManager();

    $('#applyStyle').on('click', function(){
        textManager.applyStyle('div', 'testclass');
    });

    $('#removeStyle').on('click', function(){
        textManager.removeStyle();
    });

});
```

**demo.css**

```
div {
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Meiryo'
}

#buttons{
    margin: 10px;
}

.testclass{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save my jsfiddle. I just saved it now.

Comment: My web browser is Chrome.

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not have any javascript or css.

Comment: I'm sorry!! http://jsfiddle.net/f5HaK/3/

Comment: I guess that my code doesn't work (can't select it again) because the text gets separated after applying and removing the style like 'hel' 'lo ' 'world'.

Comment: But I have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: @TaichiSato that last link you gave in the comments works properly, the spacing does get weird but the text stays selected. Also, another bug that you might want to know about, if you select some of the text, then click apply style, then click remove style, then click remove style a few more times, things start looking weird.

Comment: @Markasoftware Thank you!! I want you to watch this. Somehow, the text doesn't stay selected... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtBSJzoTmys&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text does not remain selected because you remove elements from DOM when calling *jcurnode.replaceWith(this.naked);* and the deleted nodes can't remain selected.
You can fix it by replacing the line

```
jcurnode.replaceWith(this.naked);
```

from removeStyle with this line:

```
this.execCommand('removeFormat', "");
```

Probably, you might want to see a list with all command identifiers that can be used: http://help.dottoro.com/larpvnhw.php

Comment: OMG!! I thought that 'removeFormat' works only when I wrapped text by the method 'execCommand'. Thank you !!